# How can I make this C# class and method static?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am trying to learn Linq-To-Entities. I am trying to create a static class called Items in my Data Access Layer. This class has a method to retrieve all the records in Items Entity. And then, I will use it for binding the GridView to it.
The problem is that I got the following error in my getData() method when I make that class as a static class and I don't know why:

[image]

***C# Code:***

```
public static class Items
{
    //properties
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }


    public static IEnumerable<Items> getData()
    {
        List<Items> itemsList = new List<Items>();
        using (ItemsDBEntities context = new ItemsDBEntities())
        {
            itemsList = (from item in context.Items
                        select new Items()
                        {
                            ID = item.ID,
                            Code = item.Code,
                            Name = item.Name,
                            StatusID = item.StatusID
                        }).ToList();
        }
        return itemsList;
    }
```

**Could you please tell me how to fix this error?**

Comment: could you show the code, where you use the `Items` class.

Answer (score 3):

> Could you please tell me how to fix this error?

```
//public static class Items
public class Items
{
}
```

There are clear reasons why `Items` should not be `static`.

The `getData()` method can remain static, although that doesn't seem necessary or useful either. It just makes testing a little harder. Do research state-management and the use of static in ASP.NET.

- do ask yourself why you think it needs to be static.
- anything with `Id` and  `Name` properties is an `Item`, not an `Items`.
- in C# we capitalize methods, `GetData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the static declaration for the Items class..